# AS3 - Call function in one class from another class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, event-listener

I would appreciate some help on this issue. The code I came up with is so messy that I'll rather start from scratch to get the right idea.

- I have an application with a main class.
- In that class instances of an application class and a container is defined and added to display list with addChild();
- Movie clips called "Applications" is added, and when they are added an icon of them appears in the container
- What I want to to is to click on a button in the icon which calls a function in the "application"
- That function finally alters some properties of the application such as size, position, or removes it from the display list.

I would have posted an image, but it looks like I'm not allowed.

Any general advice how this should be done? I'm not that good with AS3, but I'm familiar with some stuff. I think I lack the general logic though...

I think I should pass a reference between the classes some how, but I'm really confused on where the instances should be defined and so on. I also got some problems that event listeners won't work if they are in nested movie clips (the button in the icon in the container)

Answer (score 0):

When you click the icon, this will generate a MouseEvent. You can handle this one of two ways: your icon can translate this general event to a custom event type that is more specific to your own needs and dispatch *that* event from within the icon's Base Class, or you can just listen for the MouseEvent at a higher level and then react to it there.

I am going to post an example of what this latter approach might look like, but because I find manually instantiating and positioning to be boring, repetitive, and just generally annoying, I am going to write it as if everything is actually positioned on the stage in the IDE:

```
public class Container extends Sprite {
    protected var childApps:Vector.<Application> = new Vector.<Application>();
    protected var _activeApp:Application;
    public function Container() {
        super();
        for (var i:int=0; i &lt; numChildren; i++) {
            var childApp:Application = getChildAt(i) as Application;
            if (childApp) {
                childApps[childApps.length] = childApp;
                childApp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setActiveApp);
            }
        }
    }
    protected function setActiveApp(e:Event):void {
        _activeApp = e.currentTarget as Application;
    }

    public function get activeApp():void {
        return _activeApp;
    }
}

/****************************/

public class MainClass extends MovieClip {

    public var container:Container;
    public var growIcon:Icon;
    public var shrinkIcon:Icon;

    public function MainClass() {
        super();
        stop();
        if (growIcon) {
            growIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, grow);
            shrinkIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shrink);
        }
    }
    protected function grow(e:MoudeEvent):void {
        if (container && container.activeApp) {
            var newScale = container.activeApp.scaleX * 1.5;
            container.activeApp.scaleX = container.activeApp.scaleY = newScale;
        }
    }

    protected function shrink(e:MoudeEvent):void {
        if (container && container.activeApp) {
            var newScale = container.activeApp.scaleX * .75;
            container.activeApp.scaleX = container.activeApp.scaleY = newScale;
        }
    }

}
```

In short, avoid talking directly to sibling Classes where possible, and limit interactions from the parent to the child to exposed public properties. Expose as few properties as you can get away with.